# Gauge remove the border IE

Tags: highcharts

I need a little help.

I have made some gauges with a nice image background on it but in IE (version 9) it shows the borders of the gauge. I dont think the image is the problem because when I remove the image background, the borders are still there

The borders are showing all arround the gauge.

My code:

```
renderTo: 'clock',
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBorder: false,
        plotBackgroundColor: '#403F3F',
        plotBackgroundImage: 'gauge.png',
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderRadius: 0,
        spacingTop: 0,
        spacingRight: 0,
        spacingBottom: 0,
        spacingLeft: 0,
        plotShadow: false,
```

Anyone have a solution for me?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Theo

Comment: add working example that on jsfiddle.net to your post.

Comment: I think I have found a solution, but I dont know if this is a valid one.

i have changed the code to:

    spacingTop: -1,
    spacingRight: -1,
    spacingBottom: -1,
    spacingLeft: -1,

The borders are gone now, but Is this oke to do it this way?

Comment: I think this is bad way to remove border...

Comment: I was affraid that it is bad. But dont know what to do else. The problem is that Iam not allowed to put a image in this topic. So I cant show you what the problem is.

Comment: I think this is about css not highcharts. I suggest, add your css file this code : `img { border:none; }` , if this does not work, modify [this example.](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-clock/)...

Comment: I have upload a screenshot to my server.  [link]http://weerstation-lemmer.nl/screenshot.jpg

Comment: updated the fiddle, borders are there! [link] http://jsfiddle.net/phtvs/yY5kx/4/

Comment: Which version of IE9 do you use? Because in my it works well, and borsers don't appear. Have you enabled compatibility mode?

Comment: Iam using the 64 bit version of IE9 and not using the compatb. mode